# Charles + Android + Chrome + SSL - Handshake Failed (certificate_unknown)

Tags: android, google-chrome, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

Trying to sniff traffic between from my Android Emulator and my website via Chrome on Android Pie (9.0). Host is running macOS High Sierra with Android Studio 3.3.1 and Charles 4.2.7.

Installed both the Charles Root SSL cert and User SSL cert on the device; set up Chrome to proxy traffic to my host machine.

Requests to my site do appear in Charles, but I get the error `Client SSL handshake failed: An unknown issue occurred processing the certificate (certificate_unknown)`

Since I don't own Chrome, I can't edit its app manifest to add a network security exception.

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure your browser is using the right certificate (self-signed / global)? Is there any way to check that? I have not worked on Android development, so I am probably not able to find exact cause. but on desktop browsers It generally is either the certificate file or the path-to-certificate that causes this. Additionally [this](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/cause-ssl-handshake-failure-60530.html) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it, as of Android 11, [according to Charles Proxy official doc](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/).

> As of Android N, you need to add configuration to your app in order
> to have it trust the SSL certificates generated by Charles SSL
> Proxying. **This means that you can only use SSL Proxying with apps
> that you control.**

If you must use an Android Device/Emulator to sniff traffic, you can try with an older Android version.